# Problem installing Lubuntu in UEFI alongside Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, uefi

I have a Samsung N Series notebook with 2 GB RAM. Last year, I installed Lubuntu 17.10 but during installation I left 150-200 GB of my 500 GB Hard drive as unallocated (Only 3 primary partitions permitted in MBR).

So after a few days running Lubuntu, I deleted the root, swap and home partitions using Windows Disk Management tool. Wasn't able to boot into Windows later. So I put the live USB in and after some time searching over the Internet used LILO to get back my Windows boot loader. Windows booted fine.

Now a few days ago I tried installing Lunbuntu 17.10 again in EFI mode. Everything went fine but just as the installation was going to finish this message popped up:

**Calling 'apt -install grub-efi-amd64-signed' failed**

I used Yannubuntu's boot-repair tool, have tried installing Lubuntu with and without internet connection but its the same story every time. Installation can't go past this grub-efi thing. What should I do now?

***Edit1***: Another thing is that when choosing the boot options in Windows boot manager, only CD/DVD, Hard Drive and USB (in EFI) mode are listed. That's the reason I'm unable to load Lubuntu in CSM/Legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use a live Ubuntu and an external drive to boot the machine, mount windows partition, backup all windwows data to the external drive, mount Linux data patition, backup all Linux data to external drive. Umount everything and shutdown. Reboot with a Windows media and reinstall windows erasing every partition (this might or might not void Samsung warranty if you have a restore partition). Update the machine to the last windows update build. Turn off machine. Use a Ubuntu media to install Ubuntu and see if you can finish. If you get a successfull dual booting machine restore the backupped data.

Comment: No worries with the Samsung warranty. My laptop is >4 years old.

Comment: So installing both Windows 7 and Lubuntu in UEFI mode will work fine? The current windows is running in Legacy mode.

Comment: I'd say first you have the issue of running Windows 7 in UEFI mode. So backup, enable UEFI, install Windows 7 in UEFI mode. Then install lubuntu 17.10 in UEFI mode.